# How can I add images in ChartPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, data-visualization, jfreechart

So as shown in the figure I want to add the images on those bars, so I searched a lot to find the way to do it. Is it possible or not?

[image]

Comment: Is this using JavaScript (d3.js/chart.js) or Java (Swing/JFreeChart)?

Comment: I want to do this with swing/JFreeChart.

Comment: I thought if it is not available in JFreechart/Swing then might be possible in d3.js/chart.js.

Comment: yes There is no chartpanel in d3.js but may be possible through some other ways in d3.js/chart.js.

Comment: *"then might be possible in d3.js/chart.js"* That would make it a separate question, best asked on its own question thread.

Comment: You could try it like [this](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117612).